# AWS Route 53 blocking APIs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a NodeJS server up and running on AWS EC2. It is a t2 micro with no load balancers and no auto-scaling. On the security groups, I have:
[image]

Next, I have my domains set up on Route 53 whose nameservers are placed on name.com, and a wildcard SSL from GoDaddy.com which I have set up on ACM. I have made an endpoint on Route 53 to point to EC2 Elastic IP. Everything is set up as it should be.

Now here comes the problem. Whenever I try to hit my server endpoint using the Route 53 endpoint, it fails after two or three calls, but the elastic IP works fine. Same thing happens if I point the Route 53 URL on other resource such as CloudFront.

Normally, this wouldn't bother me if I built this server for mobile apps only. But the issue is that the Web and Server won't communicate until they are both on HTTPS.

So any ideas???

I'll provide more information of needed.

Comment: It's not Route53 that is blocking those API calls. Route53 just translates a domain name to an IP address, after which your software would be making requests directly to the IP address.

Comment: Ok, so what else can it be then?? Assuming, the IP address means the Elastic IP, then, in that case, it's something else because like I said the Elastic IP is working perfectly fine.